# UIKit Dynamics - slow moving objects won't bounce

Tags: ios, uikit, game-physics

The goal is to create an environment where an image of a ball will bounce around endlessly inside a view ***very slowly***.  I can make the endless bounce work with a high velocity, but not a slow velocity.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
UIDynamicAnimator  *animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView: self.view];

UICollisionBehavior  *ballCollision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems: @[largeBall, mediumBall, smallBall]];
[ballCollision setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary: YES];
[ballCollision setCollisionMode: UICollisionBehaviorModeBoundaries];

float force = 0.1;
int angle = 225;
NSNumber *rad = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle)];

UIPushBehavior  *smallPush = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems: @[smallBall] mode: UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];
[smallPush setAngle: [rad floatValue]];
[smallPush setMagnitude: force];

UIDynamicItemBehavior *dynamicBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems: @[smallBall]];
[dynamicBehavior setDensity: 0.0];
[dynamicBehavior setElasticity: 1.0];
[dynamicBehavior setFriction: 0.0];
[dynamicBehavior setResistance: 0.0];

[animator addBehavior: ballCollision];
[animator addBehavior: smallPush];
[animator addBehavior: dynamicBehavior];
```

My high school physics class must not have sunk in, because I can't figure out why this doesn't work.  Friction is zero, elasticity is one, the ball should bounce forever, shouldn't it?

Comment: So what does happen? Does it move at all? Does it slow down and stop?

Comment: As a slow velocity, the ball images makes contact with the edge of the view, then just slides along it.  It doesn't bounce off the "wall", it slides across it.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that UIKIt Dynamics is not physics. Apple took pains to say this repeatedly at WWDC. It's "physics-like."

`UICollisionBehavior` suppresses vector components less than 100p/s (this isn't documented; you can just work it out through experimentation). This is often what you want so things don't go bouncing forever, and makes some common uses a little simpler to implement. `UIDynamicItemBehavior` isn't really deeply integrated in my experience. It doesn't define really "fundamental" characteristics of items; it just tweaks other behaviors in ways that feel like physics.

UIKit Dynamics also has various rounding errors that make items behave in non-ideal ways when you push the edge of what a `float` can hold. The purpose of UIKit Dynamics is to put a little bounce in `UIView`, not simulate real physical interactions.

I'm not arguing that UIKit Dynamics is correct in how it's doing this. I find it challenging to work with, and it often behaves in non-obvious ways like this. If you need something that is more physics-like, you may want to explore SpriteKit instead. I would recommend opening a radar (bugreport.apple.com) about this particular issue if it impacts you.

You can experiment with this yourself with a little simpler implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  // Variables to play with
  CGFloat force = .25; // At .25, will bounce forever.
  CGFloat angle = 0;  // Play with small values to see effect.

  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIView *ball = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 300, 50, 50)];
  ball.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  [self.view addSubview:ball];

  self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView: self.view];

  UICollisionBehavior *ballCollision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems: @[ball]];
  [ballCollision setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary:YES];

  UIPushBehavior *smallPush = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ball]
                                                               mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];
  [smallPush setAngle:GetRadiansForDegrees(angle)];
  [smallPush setMagnitude: force];

  UIDynamicItemBehavior *dynamicBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ball]];
  __weak id weakBehavior = dynamicBehavior;
  [dynamicBehavior setElasticity: 1];
  [dynamicBehavior setResistance: 0.0];
  dynamicBehavior.action = ^{
    NSLog(@"linear:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint([weakBehavior linearVelocityForItem:ball]));
  };

  [self.animator addBehavior: ballCollision];
  [self.animator addBehavior: smallPush];
  [self.animator addBehavior: dynamicBehavior];
}
```

Comment: Your comments match my fears.  UIKit Dynamics is close, but not quite exact in how it does things.  By setting the Elasticity to full, and the resistance to none, the "ball" should bounce around forever -- no matter how fast it's moving.  The fact that it doesn't seems more like a bug than a feature to me.  I'll open a Radar, but I really hope someone can offer up a real-world solution for today.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Do take a look at SpriteKit; its physics tends to be much more accurate, and it actually *claims* to be a physics engine (which UIKit Dynamics explicitly disavows).

Comment: I've used SpriteKit before.  I was just hoping to try and avoid the overhead it comes with.  I only need some basic animation.  I'd almost rather write my own linear calculations to simulate the collisions that add a resource intensive SpriteKit layer for something so simple.

Comment: @Axeva Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm developing something very similar (slow moving object with bounce) and stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for exactly your use case, but it worked for mine where I didn't want my items getting stuck to each other as they slowed down

I added a delegate to detect when the collision happened, and added a small push on each item in the opposite direction of the collision so that items would never end up being stuck together